# Why do I get a type mismatch when attempting to return a value for a checked generic parameter?

Tags: kotlin

In the following code `"Happy Halloween!"`, `42`, etc. are flagged as "Type mismatch." (Required: T, Found: String (or Int)) but shouldn't the compiler be able to infer that the return value is of the correct type from the type check?

```
interface Type<T>
class StringType() : Type<String>
class IntType1() : Type<Int>
class IntType2(val a: Int, val b: Int) : Type<Int>

fun <T> something(type: Type<T>): T = when (type) {
    is StringType -> "Happy Halloween!"
    is IntType1 -> 42
    is IntType2 -> type.a * type.a + type.b * type.b + type.a * type.b
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

Comment: You have set the return type of the function to `T`, but you return the string `Happy Halloween!`. That's why you get the type mismatch.

Comment: @marstran The return type is `T` but after `type is StringType` return `true` I would expect the compiler to now know that `T` is indeed `String`.

Comment: Ah, now I see :) I'm not sure exactly why it doesn't work like you did it, but it works if you change the line to `is StringType -> "Happy Halloween!" as T`

Comment: @marstran Such a cast would be unsafe as `is StringType -> 42 as T` would also compile which is not what I want. I want the compiler to help me make sure I return the appropriate type.

Comment: I think that its just that Smart Cast is not smart enough to reason about generic types. I would assume it only checks types at the current level, and does not go deep into type declaration.

Comment: @rafal-g Perhaps but this doesn't even seem like a cast of any kind should be necessary. I thought/hoped that this was simply how generics work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this:

```
interface Type<T>
class StringType() : Type<String>
class IntType1() : Type<Int>
class IntType2(val a: Int, val b: Int) : Type<Int>

inline fun <reified T> something(type: Type<T>): T {
    val result = when(type) {
        is StringType -> "Happy Halloween"
        is IntType1 -> 42
        is IntType2 -> type.a * type.a + type.b * type.b + type.a * type.b
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
    return if (result is T) result else throw Exception() 
}
```

Running the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(something(StringType()))
    println(something(IntType1()))
    println(something(IntType2(2, 3)))
}
```

Will give you this output:

```
Happy Halloween
42
19
```

Learn more about inline functions and reified parameters here: [Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler applies type erasure the return type is going to be defined. So, let's say, you use a String... your method is going to be like:

```
fun something(type: Type<String>): String = when (type) {
    is StringType -> "Happy Halloween!"
    is IntType1 -> 42 //Wrong: you must return String!
    is IntType2 -> type.a * type.a + type.b * type.b + type.a * type.b   
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

This thing is: **you must know your return type at compile time**. If you dont know this, you have to tell that to the compiler:

```
fun <T> something(type: Type<T>): Any = when (type) {
    is StringType -> "blabla"
    is IntType1 -> 42
    is IntType2 -> type.a * type.a + type.b * type.b + type.a * type.b
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

Sorry this code it's not what you are hopping, you are going to make a cast after the method is returned...

But you can this:

```
fun <T> something(type: Type<T>): T = when (type) {
        is StringType -> type.b
        //is IntType1 -> 42 remove this!
        is IntType2 -> type.a * type.a + type.b * type.b + type.a * type.b
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
```

assuming the type.a and type.b are parametized as T. Then your code will work just fine.

Comment: I've updated my example code to clarify my use case. I should have been more explicit that there would be multiple sub types of `Type<T>` and that the function would do multiple `is <SubType>` checks to determine what to return.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited my answer. I hope it helps now.

Answer (score 0):

If I simplify your example a little:

```
interface Type<T>

fun <T> something(type: Type<T>): T = when (type) {
    is Type<String> -> "Happy Halloween!"
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

the compiler now complains that he: `cannot check for instance of erased type`

So the problem is that because of type erasure there is no difference between `Type<String>` and `Type<Int>` at run time, so the compiler wont allow that.

You can try to use something like Gson's `TypeToken<T>` or Jackson's [`TypeReference<T>`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)
The docs refer to this blog post explaining the idea: http://gafter.blogspot.ca/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Comment: This is not the case: the author intentionally used `StringType` (a subclass of `Type<String>`), because **it is** possible to make an is-check for `StringType` at runtime.

Comment: It's possible to make the check but it's still going to think that `StringType` is just `type`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that `StringType` will still just be `Type<>` with no actual type information added to it. So the `when` cannot tell the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator, much like Java's `instanceof` operator, is performed at **runtime**.

So, at **compile time**, the compiler does not know the actual type, hence you get a compilation error.

Here is another simple example:

```
fun <T>f(t: T): T
{
    if (t is Int) return 3 // compilation error
    else return t
}
```